# Excel PowerQuery: update all referencing tables with single API call

Tags: excel, powerquery

In Excel PowerQuery I have one "combined" API call returning a list of records with ("table") identifier which I already split into different tables (all with a slightly different column structure). I use the API table as a reference for the other tables.

I was hoping to accelerate the retrieval of data having only one API call. But now when I click the Update all connections button all tables referencing the API query seem to do the same thing -> calling the API connection - hence it runs multiple times, slowing everything down.

Is there a way to only update the API table which then automatically updates all other tables?
Ideally in PowerQuery because there I have created my steps to build each table/column structure as desired.

In the end I want my tables to appear in PowerQuery and then load them into individual sheets:

[image]

Comment: I'm not set up to test this but what about [`Table.StopFolding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-stopfolding)? If you add that as a step at the end of your `API_Query` query, does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately StopFolding does not work because it's not a native SQL query but I tested it anyways with pretty much the same result +- a few seconds.

Comment: One workaround may be to load API_Query to a table, and then load that Excel table back into PQ where it then becomes the source for the final output tables. It's not a perfect solution as you may need to 'stage' the refreshes (ie refresh API_Query first, so it loads the latest data to Excel and then refresh the others) but it may work for you

Comment: [Normally reference query duplicates calls unless it's a dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/power-query-referenced-queries) --  For excel, there's a way to have one query load to a cached table, and your queries use that. I don't think you need any API or VBA. The disadvantage is you have to hit refresh twice. I've seen it mentioned on [/r/excel](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel) a few times. I don't have the exact link on me